# Equation with several exponents

Tags: equation-solving

Is there a way to get the result for this value of x?

```
x^x^(x^(1/6)/6)==Sqrt[2^9]^(2*Sqrt[2])^(2/3+2*Sqrt[2])
```

I've tried `Solve`, `FindInstance` and I did not get a solution

I tried this:

```
Solve[x^x^(x^(1/6)/6)==Sqrt[2^9]^(2*Sqrt[2])^(2/3+2*Sqrt[2]),{x}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
NSolve[x^x^(x^(1/6)/6) == Sqrt[2^9]^(2*Sqrt[2])^(2/3 + 2*Sqrt[2]), x, Reals]
(*{x->512}*)
```

Comment: Little detail that makes all the difference. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: `Solve[x^x^(x^(1/6)/6) == Sqrt[2^9]^(2*Sqrt[2])^(2/3 + 2*Sqrt[2]), x, Reals]` also works!

Answer (score 3):

This is essentially the same as Ulrich's solution but provides the motivation for restricting the domain of [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)

```
eqn = x^x^(x^(1/6)/6) == Sqrt[2^9]^(2*Sqrt[2])^(2/3 + 2*Sqrt[2]) // 
  Simplify

(* x^x^(x^(1/6)/6) == 8^(3 8^Sqrt[2]) *)
```

The RHS of `eqn` is real

```
Element[eqn[[-1]], Reals]

(* True *)
```

Consequently, finding the [`FunctionDomain`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html) for the LHS of `eqn`

```
const = FunctionDomain[eqn[[1]], x] // Simplify

(* x > 0 *)
```

Then,

```
Solve[eqn && const, x][[1]]

(* {x -> 512} *)
```